# Apache HttpClient: how to send headers along with CONNECT request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons, apache-commons-httpclient

I need to connect to a proxy that reads headers in CONNECT requests. I mean specifically the headers that are passed along with CONNECT, before switching to en HTTPS-encrypted stream.

Is that possible with HttpClient? Its default behaviour seems to be to push all headers through the encrypted stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure you should be doing this (I personally do not see a valid reason for adding custom headers to CONNECT requests) but this is how this could be done with HttpClient 4.3 or newer

```
class MyHttpClientBuilder extends HttpClientBuilder {

    @Override
    protected ClientExecChain createMainExec(
            final HttpRequestExecutor requestExec,
            final HttpClientConnectionManager connManager,
            final ConnectionReuseStrategy reuseStrategy,
            final ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy,
            final HttpProcessor proxyHttpProcessor,
            final AuthenticationStrategy targetAuthStrategy,
            final AuthenticationStrategy proxyAuthStrategy,
            final UserTokenHandler userTokenHandler) {

        final HttpProcessor myProxyHttpProcessor = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(new RequestTargetHost(), new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                request.addHeader("Hello", "Mom says hi");
            }
        });

        return super.createMainExec(requestExec, connManager, reuseStrategy, keepAliveStrategy,
                myProxyHttpProcessor, targetAuthStrategy, proxyAuthStrategy, userTokenHandler);
    }
}

HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = new MyHttpClientBuilder();
CloseableHttpClient client = MyHttpClientBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Many thanks! Why do this: the proxy I'm talking to requires some instructions to do its job. With regular HTTP requests it takes the headers and strips them from the relayed request. With HTTPS requests, there is no other way than sending headers along with CONNECT.

Comment: Someone is probably being too creative with HTTP protocol

Comment: I accepted your answer but it doesn't seem to work. The header is added, but only to the encrypted stream. Any idea?

Comment: It cannot.The protocol processor for the normal requests (which you refer to as encrypted stream) is initialized in ProtocolExec. Protocol interceptor used by MainExec is used to process outgoing CONNECT requests only